# Mongodb: Failed to run mongod.service

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

i dont know why this happening. its working normal before.

but now i cant start mongod service.

after research on google and i cant run `/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf` by manual.

then i decide to create the `.service` file to run the command on background.

here's file that i write

```
[Unit]
Description=High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database
After=network.target

[Service]
User=mongodb
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

i save it on `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service`

but when i run `systemctl start mongod` its show me nothing output.

and i check the status with `systemctl status mongod`

and give me failed messages. here's detail message:

> mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database    Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service;
>   enabled; vendor preset: enabled)    Active: failed (Result: exit-code)
>   since Mon 2019-10-28 10:47:21 UTC; 27s ago   Process: 17668
>   ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
>   (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)  Main PID: 17668 (code=exited,
>   status=1/FAILURE)
>
> Oct 28 10:47:21 production.seletra.com systemd[1]: Started
>   High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database. Oct 28
>   10:47:21 production.seletra.com systemd[1]: Starting High-performance,
>   schema-free document-oriented database... Oct 28 10:47:21
>   production.seletra.com mongod[17668]: 2019-10-28T10:47:21.743+0000 F
>   CONTROL  Failed global initialization: BadValue Invalid or no user
>   locale set. Please ensure LANG...t correctly. Oct 28 10:47:21
>   production.seletra.com systemd[1]: mongod.service: main process
>   exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Oct 28 10:47:21
>   production.seletra.com systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed
>   state. Oct 28 10:47:21 production.seletra.com systemd[1]:
>   mongod.service failed. Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to
>   show in full.

how i can fix it?

or maybe is there any way to manipulated this code `/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf` to run on background?

Comment: I'd same problem but if run mongodb with "sudo mongod" or "sudo mongod --dbpath /data/db" it run without any problem! but I was looking for way I'll be able run mongod at the start up on Debian 10 64bit